# How to assign a value to a django form field in the template?

Tags: python, html, django

I was wondering how you can assign a value to a django form field in the template.

I know that there is other ways to assign an initial value in django, but I need to assign the value in the template because the variable is only present in the template.

The way to do this with a normal html form would be this:

```
{% for thing in things %}
  <p> {{ thing.content }} </p>
  <!-- Reply form -->
  <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="replyingto" value="{{ thing.number }}">
    <input type="text" label="Reply"></input>
  </form>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I need to use a django form.

I also know there is a way to assign a label to a field in the template, like this:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{{ form.field.errors }}
   <label for="{{ form.field.id_for_label }}"> field </label>
{{ form.field }}
```

So my question is basically how you would go about doing the example above but instead of assigning a label, assign a value.

---

I've found a solution!

What I did was type the html manually as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman/) suggested and assigned the value that way.

For anyone who is wondering how I did it here is an [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options).

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the code you have. Creating the HTML manually doesn't prevent you from using a Django form in the view.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Can I use an html form instead of a django form and parse those values in the view?

Comment: If you want, but you said you wanted to use a Django form.

Comment: Well if there's a way to parse the values from a normal html form I don't really need a django form. And if there is a way, my question would be how you would do that.

Comment: Can you add the views.py and forms.py code for this page? There is a better way to do this in code I'm sure.

Answer (score 3):

you do it in Python, which can then be available to the HTML form or generator

in `forms.py` you can set the `initial` property to define the default value of the field.

ex: `name = forms.CharField(initial='class')`

or dynamically in `views.py` you can use a `dict`.

ex: `f = CommentForm(initial={'name': 'instance'})`

Once available within the `form` instance you can use `{{ form.field.value }}`
in your HTML or automatically with a generator

Extended reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#s-dynamic-initial-values

Answer (score 3):

You could render the form out manually field by field but then render all other fields using Django template interpolation, but your hidden field you can render manually. e.g.

```
{% for thing in things %}
  <p> {{ thing.content }} </p>
  <!-- Reply form -->
  <form FORM_PARAMS_HERE >
    <div class="form-row">
        {{ form.other_form_field.errors }}
        {{ form.other_form_field.label_tag }} {{ form.other_form_field }}
    </div>
    ... (more form rows)
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="hidden" name="replyingto" id="replyingto_id" value="{{ thing.number }}">
        <input type="text" label="Reply"></input>
    </div>
  </form>
{% endfor %}
```

I faced this exact problem and was finally able to resolve it as I think you want after finding [this excellent and hard to find reference](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html#expanding-the-form-fields) on it.