# How to save multiple records using a for loop

Tags: django

I would like to echo students to enter each students marks against the students something like [how the form should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y27l2.png).

```
{% for student in students %}

                <input type="text" name="child" value="{{ student.child.id }}" class="form-group" hidden="hidden"></input>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{student.reg_no}}</td>
                    <td>{{ student.child }}</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="marks" class="form-group" min="0"></input></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

my model.py

```
class Mark(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    marks_class = models.ForeignKey(Classe, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    stream = models.ForeignKey(Stream, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    exam_set = models.ForeignKey(ExamSet, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=current_year, validators=[MinValueValidator(2020), max_value_current_year])
    marks = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

I selected the students for entering marks like this

```
students = ClassInformation.objects.filter(year_of_registration=year, current_class=marks_class, stream=stream).order_by('child')
```

I assigned other values like

*The values are first selected*

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for student in students:
        form = MarkCreateForm(request.POST,)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.subject = subject
            form.instance.marks_class = marks_class
            form.instance.stream = stream
            form.instance.year = year
            form.instance.term = term
            form.instance.exam_set = exam_set

            try:
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, f'Marks Submitted Successfully')
                return redirect('choose-subject')
            except:
                messages.warning(request, f'Marks already entered for some students')
```

**now the challenge is the last record only gets submitted and formsets seem not to do the job pretty much good**

I followed something from here but the answer seem not there yet.   [How to assign a value to a django form field in the template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994963/how-to-assign-a-value-to-a-django-form-field-in-the-template)

Comment: Looks like you need to use a formset rather than a form. Take a look at the Django documentation for model formset.

Comment: Am a little bit new to django, can you be more specific?

Comment: A form is used out of the box for saving a single record. For saving multiple records (in your case many `Mark`s) at once, you need a set of forms, in Django that's called a formset. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: formsets could not do the job but l was able to pick the values as a list and save using a bulkcreate